# Insert sequence taking long time

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

I have a table in Oracle:

```
table1

record_id    variable     value
1            100          50
1            101          40
2            100          30
2            101          60
1            102          100
```

It has over 7 million rows. I want to add another column as unique ID. So, the table would look something like:

```
table1

id          record_id    variable     value
1           1            100          50
2           1            101          40
3           2            100          30
4           2            101          60
5           1            102          100
```

But when I try to update it using:

UPDATE table1
SET id = my_sequence.nextval;

It is taking a long time. Is there a faster way to get this done?

Here is the create table query:

```
CREATE TABLE "ABCUSER"."NUM_VAL"
("RECORD_ID" NUMBER(*,0),
"VAR" NUMBER,
"VAR_SEQUENCE" NUMBER,
"VAR_DATATYPE" NUMBER,
"CREATED_DATE" DATE,
"UPDATED_DATE" DATE,
"VAR_VALUE_NUMBER" VARCHAR2(40 BYTE),
"VAR_VALUE_TEXT" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE),
"VAR_VALUE_DATE" DATE,
"ID" NUMBER
) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE
PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
NOCOMPRESS NOLOGGING
STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
TABLESPACE "USERS" ;

CREATE INDEX "ABCUSER"."IMD_TB_UNIQUE_ID" ON "ABCUSER"."NUM_VAL" ("RECORD_ID")
PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS
STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
TABLESPACE "USERS" ;
```

Sequence:

CREATE SEQUENCE  "ABCUSER"."MY_SEQUENCE"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 10186338807 CACHE 100 NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;

Comment: @MikeNakis - done

Comment: pOrinG's answer will work, but I do not think that it will yield any great performance benefits, because sequences are highly optimized.  If the sequence is the bottleneck, it is very easy to alter the `CACHE` clause of the sequence from `100` to `1000` or to `10000` to improve its performance by orders of magnitude.  I think you should also define what you mean by "a long time", because 7 million records will take some time to update even in the most optimal scenario.

Comment: Which version of Oracle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updating all 7 million rows (the whole table) must take some time.
A faster way is to create a copy of this table:

```
CREATE TABLE NUM_VAL_copy AS SELECT 
   "RECORD_ID"  ,
   "VAR" ,
   "VAR_SEQUENCE" ,
   "VAR_DATATYPE"  ,
   "CREATED_DATE" ,
   "UPDATED_DATE" ,
   "VAR_VALUE_NUMBER",
   "VAR_VALUE_TEXT" ,
   "VAR_VALUE_DATE" ,
   my_sequence.nextval AS "ID"
FROM NUM_VAL;
```

then index new_table, grant privileges, add constraints on new table etc.
and finally drop old table and rename new table to old name:

```
DROP TABLE NUM_VAL;
RENAME NUM_VAL_COPY TO NUM_VAL;
```

---

Please check the documentation for details: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9019.htm#SQLRF01608

Answer (score 0):

If you want the sequence to be starting with 1...2...3... on wards then you can use the following.

```
update table_name set unique_seq = rownum;
```

I tried it on a table with 6 records and it works fine. I am not 100% sure if this is the ideal way but I think it will be faster than nextval.

Later on if you still want to you your defined sequence for some reason, you can update the oracle sequence to start from the max(unique_seq) number.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are using Oracle RAC, this might be an issue. A small cached sequence will have performance impact. Use no order , cache to create your sequence.
2. 7 million rows is not a big number. You might want to check if you have application block issue during your update. That is a DBA job. They will need to check lock for you.
3. If you can do a create table as select to add values, it will be much faster than update.

rename table1 to table2 ; 
create table table1 select /*+ append */ *, [idvalue] id  from table2 ;